# Como faço para ler da posição x até a posição y de uma linha no node.js através da função readFileSync?

Tags: node.js

Tenho um determinado arquivo .txt do qual pretendo pegar algumas 
informações, porém essas informações estão
fixas em uma determinada posição da linha do texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando é especificada uma codificação de texto para leitura no `readFileSync` o retorno da função passa a ser do tipo `string` em vez de ser do tipo `buffer`.

Por este motivo pode fazer a leitura em forma de `string` com algo como:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let textoFicheiro = fs.readFileSync("arquivo.txt", "utf-8");
```

Depois pode usar o método `substring` da `string` para ir buscar uma informação a um determinado sitio com base em posições:

```
let textoParcial = textoFicheiro.substring(10,20);
```

Em que no exemplo acima ia buscar o texto da posição `10` á posição `19`, uma vez que a posição final é exclusive.

**Edit**:

Para obter o conteúdo do arquivo por linhas basta fazer `split` pelo separador de cada linha `\n`, ou `\r\n` e depois aplicar os mesmos princípios de `substring` ou `charAt`:

```
const linhas = textoFicheiro.split("\r\n"); //obter um array de linhas do ficheiro

//obter o caractere para a segunda linha (indice 1) e na posição 10
let caracterLinha2Posicao10 = linhas[1].charAt(10); 

//obter na terceira linha a porção de texto que vai do caractere 15 ao 21
let textoLinha3Pos15_20 = linhas[2].substring(15,21);
```

Comment: Isso funciona se tenho apenas uma linha na string, mas no meu caso tenho varias linhas, e cada linha será uma posição diferente, como faço um loop na string para identificar a linha que estou ?